# "Error inflating class menu" - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #119: Error inflating class menu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am working on an Android app and I try to implement Social share buttons into the app.

I checked the Android documentation for sharing - [Sharing simple data](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction) and implemented the code there; however, the app crashes when launching with the error message `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #119: Error inflating class menu`

I changed the position and constraints of the Layout files with no success.

The Main Activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Button buttonStart, buttonStop, buttonPlayLastRecordAudio,
            buttonStopPlayingRecording ;
    String AudioSavePathInDevice = null;
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder ;
    Random random ;
    String AudioFileName = "Recorded-Audio-on-";
    public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;
    private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        /*Add in Oncreate() funtion after setContentView()*/
        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        buttonStart = findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonStop =  findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonPlayLastRecordAudio = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        buttonStopPlayingRecording = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
        buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
        random = new Random();
        final String TAG = "IntentLogger";
        ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        final int day = mIntent.getIntExtra("day", 0);
        final int month = mIntent.getIntExtra("month", 0);
        final int year = mIntent.getIntExtra("year", 0);
        Log.v(TAG, "Data String in Main Activity: " + day + month + year);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(checkPermission()) {
                    AudioSavePathInDevice =
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                                    CreateRandomAudioFileName(5)  + day + month + year + "AudioRecording.3gp";
                    MediaRecorderReady();
                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                    buttonStop.setEnabled(true);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording started",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    requestPermission();
                }

            }
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(true);
                buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
                buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording Completed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                    SecurityException, IllegalStateException {

                buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(true);

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AudioSavePathInDevice);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaPlayer.start();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording Playing",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        buttonStopPlayingRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
                buttonStopPlayingRecording.setEnabled(false);
                buttonPlayLastRecordAudio.setEnabled(true);

                if(mediaPlayer != null){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    MediaRecorderReady();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void MediaRecorderReady(){
        mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
    }


    public String CreateRandomAudioFileName(int string){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( string );
        int i = 0 ;
        while(i < string ) {
            stringBuilder.append(AudioFileName.
                    charAt(random.nextInt(AudioFileName.length())));

            i++ ;
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new
                String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO}, RequestPermissionCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestPermissionCode:
                if (grantResults.length> 0) {
                    boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (StoragePermission && RecordPermission) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                RECORD_AUDIO);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            // Handle the camera action
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseDateActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}


The activity_main.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


The app_bar_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

The content_main.xml with the Share Menu:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:paddingRight="5sp"
        android:text="@string/text_recording_to"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:paddingRight="5sp"
        android:text="@string/text_send_by"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="184dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="283dp"
            android:text="Record" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="STOP" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Play" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="STOP PLAYING RECORDING " />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
            android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="Share" />
    </menu>
```

I know that there is a problem with inflating the social share menu but I don´t get to the point why the app is crashing; hence, any help or hints would be very much appreciated!

Comment: `<menu>` elements do not go in layout files. They go in their own files under `res/menu/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #119: Error
>   inflating class menu"

You should try with

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
```

**Example**

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:title="@string/share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

Read [**`Use action views and action providers`**](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views)

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:title="@string/share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />


or


<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:title="@string/share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" 
/>
```